# Google Talk on ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, gtalk

is there any way how to use Google Talk chat on ubuntu touch aquaris e4.5? In internet browser is not possible force loading of full pages, all pages are show in mobile version, so i cannot use chat directly on gmail website and application is missing as well.